# HTTP/2 specific headers

Tags: http2

Where can I find a complete guide of http2 specific headers (`:method` `:status` `:path` etc..)

There's nothing on MDN, I found articles what describe HTTP/2 protocol but cannot find a complete list of these headers

Comment: Try https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are defined in the HTTP/2 RFC specification: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540

And in particular on [sections 8.1.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.1) which defines what they are:

> While HTTP/1.x used the message start-line (see [RFC7230], Section 3.1) to convey the target URI, the method of the request, and the status code for the response, HTTP/2 uses special pseudo-header fields beginning with ':' character (ASCII 0x3a) for this purpose.
>
> Pseudo-header fields are not HTTP header fields.  Endpoints MUST NOT generate pseudo-header fields other than those defined in this document.

And in [Sections 8.1.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.3) and [8.1.2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.3) which defines the request and response pseudo headers respectively and lists them as follows:

**Request**

- :method
- :scheme
- :authority
- :path

**Response**

- :status